# Set of all HB extension is convex.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C$ be the set of all Hahn Banach Extensions of a function. I have shown it to be non empty and closed. But how to show that $C$ is a convex set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A$ be a subspace of a Banach space $\mathcal B$, and assume $f,f':\mathcal B\to K$ are both extensions of $f_0:\mathcal A\to K$.

Then $\ g:=\lambda\cdot f\ +\ (1-\lambda)\cdot f'\ $ is also an extension of $f_0$.

If $\ \|f\|=\|f'\|=\|f_0\|\ $ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then for a vector $b\in\mathcal B$ with $\|b\|=1$, we have
$$\matrix{|g(b)|&=&|\lambda\cdot f(b)+(1-\lambda)\cdot f'(b)|&\le \\
&\le&\lambda\cdot|f(b)|+(1-\lambda)\cdot|f'(b)| & \le \\
&\le& \lambda\cdot\|f\|+(1-\lambda)\cdot\|f'\| & = & \|f_0\|}$$
On the other hand, as $g|_{\mathcal A}=f_0$, we have $\|g\|\ge\|f_0\|$.

Comment: but how do you claim that $\|g\| = \|\lambda\cdot f\ +\ (1-\lambda)\cdot f'\|$

Comment: I updated my answer with this.